# Why does the query plan start with a not-filtered-for table when the filtered-for table's entries exceed a certain threshold?

Tags: query-performance, execution-plan, mariadb-10.3

We process data for our customers. Each *customerrequest* and is associated with one or more *items* (less than two on average) and falls into one of <100 *categories*, foreign keys to which are also present on the items. Customers often want tabular views/exports of their items that include columns of all three tables. Our ORM generates a reasonable-looking query along the lines of

```
SELECT *
FROM customeritem itm
  INNER JOIN customerrequest req ON itm.request_id=req.id
  INNER JOIN category cat ON cat.id=itm.category_id
WHERE customerrequest.customer_id=123
```

This works reasonably well for many customers, producing a query whose ANALYZE-is looks like this:

[image: query plan for customers with not too many requests]

The query plan starts with the *requests* table on which the WHERE condition operates, then joins the *items*, then the *categories*, which intuitively seems the only way to go. However, for customers with many requests, a different plan is chosen and the query takes ages to execute (ANALYZE alone usually takes minutes):

[image: query plan with many requests]

Now the query plan starts with the (unfiltered) *category* table, then joins the *items* and only as a last step the *requests* table on which the WEHRE condition (which shrinks to results from an 8-digit to a 5 or 6-digit number) operates. If I remove the *category* join from the select, the query plan resembles the good one above (minus the final row for category join, of course).

Is there an intuitive explanation why this happens?

Comment: The full select statement might prove interesting, as would the analysis in a legible format.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Sorry, the `SELECT *` got lost initially. I added a few words on why I find the second query plan odd. What further information were you thinking of?

Comment: The same information, but in text format, not a picture.  Although, description of the tables and indexes involved could help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've noticed the large discrepancy between rows and r_rows for customeritem in the second analysis.  According to MariaDB's manual, that table could use an "analyze" itself.